# MAVEN: I want to copy-dependencies for all child modules to a single lib folder, but i don't want the jars built for each child-module to be included

Tags: java, docker, maven, packaging

I'm copying all dependencies in a top level lib directory from all child-modules, I use

```
<outputDirectory>${env.PWD}/lib</outputDirectory>
```

to achieve this (as it's always triggered form root in my cicd).

Now i use this lib to create my docker image, and because these lib are pretty big (~600MB) i want to cache this layer unless it's changed.

The problem is that every time i compile, it copies child-module's jars as well inside lib folder, which is not desirable for me. I'm explicitly copying my jars in next layer of dockerfile. This is happening because **child-module-1** is a dependency in **child-module-2,** hence when copy-dependencies goal for **child-module-2** is executed it copies **child-module-1** as well into libs!!

Below is the config i'm using.

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                ${dependency.output.dir}
              </outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              <excludeScope>provided</excludeScope>
              <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
              <!-- <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive> -->
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

I don't want to include any exclusions inside child POM as this is going to be my standard pom for all projects, which shouldn't require any change in child-modules!.

Comment: The first thing that pops into my mind then is to declare the child modules as provided. They'll be on the compile time classpath but be expected to be available at runtime so won't be part of the deployable. But that might have other consequences only you can know about.

Comment: I don't want to make any changes in the child pom.xml as long as possible, any other way i can achieve this from parent pom?
Also, will this not break my fat jar deployments?

Comment: That's what I mean, you didn't mention any fat jar deployments. I would add that to the question.

Comment: After reading the documentation, what do you expect copy-dependencies to do?

Comment: Can you make an example project on github or alike... apart from that I don't understand what your real problem is here? Why do you need to copy files into a lib directory? Should be a kind of distribution archive/directory or alike?